# Sending file attachment in the email contact form

Tags: 8

I have added a file field in a contact form. The client is receiving the email and there is the link of file. She now needs the file in attachment. Is there any module or code that could send the contact form field now in the attachment? I have searched but couldn't find something yet. Many thanks!

Comment: If you can use another module, you can use webform which far more superior than the built-in contact form

Comment: You should install the `webform` module, to accomplish this. Then follow this [guide](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/webform/webform-cookbook/how-to-send-email-attachments), which explains how to send files as email attachments using webform.